# expressing opinion adding し at the end of adjective

Tags: grammar, particle-し

I have two dialogues:

> 1. かわい ： 沖縄料理は 食べましたか。
>      ホセ   ： ええ、もちろんです。おいしいし、ヘルシーだし、つまも 私も 気に いりまた。

> 2. かわい ： ホテルは よかったですか。
>       ホセ ： ええ。へやは ひろくてあかるいし、へやから 海が みえたし、さいこうでした。
>              かわいさんの おすすめの ホテルに して よかったです。

I don't understand why in the first one they added だ to ヘルシー to make ヘルシーだし but they didn't add it to ひろくてあかるい to make ひろくてあかるいし. Am I missing some rule?

Comment: So your question is why だ doesn't come after あかるい?

Comment: I more interested in why だ come afterヘルシ, I have seen more examples when there is no だ added. I would like to know if there is a rule I could use for when to put it and when not.

Comment: `Am I missing some rule?`  Yes, you are.  Hint:  What part of speech is 「ヘルシー」 in Japanese?

Comment: isn't adjective? just as あかるい is? English is not my first or even the second language so I'm not sure how it's called. The part of speech that accompanies noun

Comment: ヘルシー and あかるい are not the same part of speech as each other in Japanese.